# Razor checkbox stops working when adding an ID css selector

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to wire up some jquery to retrieve the state of a checkbox. I'm finding that adding an ID type css selector to my check box disables
my ability to turn it's value on or off. No jquery wired up yet and no errors in background window. Just adding 'id="chkb"'to the below code freezes the checkbox in an on state and where it will not toggle on or off.

**This works**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport">
    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport"></label>
</div>
```

**This does not work:**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="chkb" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport">
    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport"></label>
</div>
```

**Found my issue - needed 'for="chkb"':**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="chkb" asp-for="myReportModel.chkParams.ReportType_PushReport" checked="@(Model.myReportModel.chkParams.ReportType_PushReport == true)">
    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.chkParams.ReportType_PushReport" for="chkb"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You could simply use the browser developer tools to get the id that was generated by the input tag helper instead of overwriting it with your own.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this issue is resulting from the tag helper, when we have `asp-for="xxx"`, then after rendering the html, the DOM would have id and name with value of "xxx". I have a test with code below and let's see the test result.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input asp-for="IsAdmin" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="control-label">is admin</label>
    <span asp-validation-for="IsAdmin" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="changeState" value="change State" />
    <input type="button" id="changeState2" value="change State for chkb id" />
    <input type="button" id="addId" value="add Id" />
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#addId").click(function () {
            $("#IsAdmin").attr("id", "chkb");
        });
        $("#changeState").click(function () {
            if ($('#IsAdmin').is(":checked"))
                $("#IsAdmin").prop('checked', false);
            else
                $("#IsAdmin").prop('checked', true);
        });
        $("#changeState2").click(function () {
            if ($('#chkb').is(":checked"))
                $("#chkb").prop('checked', false);
            else
                $("#chkb").prop('checked', true);
        });
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-> in your case problem in which is to add 'for' attribute to the  element and set into the same value as the 'id' attribute of the  element.

-> adding for="chkb" to the  element,which clicking on the label will toggle the checkbox correctly.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="chkb" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport">
    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="myReportModel.ReportType_PushReport" for="chkb"></label>
</div>
```